Are there any irregular groupings that are played in the time of a single beat of the same value?
I saw a source today where there were basically some questions and answers, as such:
Why use irregular groupings?
**answer
Why are triplets and sextuplets not considered an irregular grouping in compound time?
**answer
There was this one question, which itself I don't have any problems with, since it's very simple in itself. However, it was worded quite weirdly: "Are irregular groupings always played in the time of a single beat of the same value?" Then they go on and explain how they [irregular groupings] are "not always" played in the time of a single beat of the same value, and summarize how that in simple time, quintuplets, sextuplets and septuplets are generally played in the same time as four notes of the same value. (there is much more, but I chose not to include it as this whole part isn't really relevant.)
My question is, based on the wording of the problem, specifically the "always" part in "are irregular groupings always played in the time of a single beat of the same value?" and the "no, not always" that is written in the answer, does that mean that sometimes they are? (As in, are irregular groupings sometimes played in the time of a single beat of the same value?) This leads to the question in the title.
So now, I'm curious as to whether the wording is just not clear and badly written or if there is such a scenario. (ty if you are willing to help~)
note: sorry if this is still hard to understand, I don't know if the way I wrote it is too "extra" or whatnot ^^

Assuming "irregular groupings" are just another name for tuplets (e.g. the definition in How to remember how much irregular groupings are worth)...
Yes, sometimes, irregular groupings are played in the time of a single beat of the same value. In fact, you can argue that one of the most common types of irregular grouping, the triplet, is often played in the time of a single beat of the same value. ...Or, at least, an 8th-note triplet is played in the time of a quarter note in 4/4 time, 3/4 time, and more. Note that a quarter note takes up a single beat in each of those time signatures.
Your "in simple time, quintuplets, sextuplets and septuplets are generally played in the same time as four notes of the same value" is more of a reference to how a tuplet or irregular grouping can take up (the time of) an entire measure instead.
I have also seen quarter-note triplets several times before, which all take up 2 beats of 4/4 time.

The wording is simply wrong.  Any number of notes designated as fitting under a single beat, whether it's two, three, four, five, or whatever, is to be played within the time of that single beat.  This is of course subject to whatever rubato is applied (or not).
